# iOS Application (xCode alternative)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, windows, macos

Is there any way to develop an iOS application on a Windows machine (Using Obj-C) ? and It is possible compile and install the application on an iOS device ? (Without a Apple developper account).

In other word, is there an "Windows" xCode ?

Comment: I already checked that answer. But I'm searching for some new answers, new frameworks... Thank you !

Comment: There are some multi cross tools: Xamarin, etc. but you may need to have at least a Mac at the some point. And a developer ($99 account) is needed if you want to publish apps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is there any way to develop an iOS app with Obj-C (on Windows for sure) ? Because Xamarin uses C#

Comment: @RDC, I already checked. But those answers are not useful for me.

Comment: How do they not help you?  What is your question so different from others?  You only have a few sentences.  What's so unique about your question?

Comment: @ElTomato, I ask for an alternative of XCode on windows. In the other answers, they give some tools with other langages, but I want to create an app with Obj-C in a Windows and to deploy it in my iOs device without a OSX. Thank you for your answer tho

Comment: @pyouslh you will be able to write code using Objective-C on windows, but you can't compile then since you will need to SDK with the iOS frameworks. This SDK and its frameworks are not available on any other platform then OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can develop the application for iOS by using `third party development tools` like - UNITY 3d and others.

You can install app in to the device with-out the apple developer account ,
Just follow these steps.

1- uninstall the x-code from your system.
2- Install x-code 7 or higher .
3- remove all signing identity from keychain.
4- Just open `Preferences` .
5- Add your apple id (not required to pay 99$ for developer account).
6- Connect your device with x-code.
7- Run the app .
8- while it is showing the signing identity select your personal account.

It is working for me.

Comment: I heard that you can install your iOs app on your iOS device (even without an Apple dev account). It's available only on Xcode ?

Comment: I think never or i read more today about ... .. 
I will give you update tomorrow.
But i am sure about it.

Comment: Yes you can self sign app nowadays, but this still requires an Apple Developers Account. But you do not need to pay for your account to run apps on your own phone. But be aware there is a time limit to these apps, so they wil only run for a couple of days. You can just sign in in Xcode with your Apple ID and run apps on your phone.

Comment: I have edited my answer , Please follow that . Thanks for updating me. @rckoenes